# logging into modal form with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to log into https://www.racingandsports.com.au/. the login link opens a modal form but Im having trouble with sending user/pass to it. I'm using the below code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.racingandsports.com.au/")

sign_in_button = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="btn_login")
sign_in_button.click()

username_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "lb-username")))
password_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "lb-password")))

username_field.send_keys("your_username")
password_field.send_keys("your_password")

#login_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, value = "btnLogin").click()


#WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_contains("https://www.racingandsports.com.au/"))


time.sleep(10)
#driver.quit()
```

I can open the modal ok from the link but when trying to send user/pass to it I'm getting

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

can anyone point me in the right direction please, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script was pretty close. I made a couple changes and it's working fine.

1. The site is slow to load. Because of that, you'll want to use a `WebDriverWait` on the first `.find_element()` as you did with the others.
2. You were waiting for presence. Presence just means that the element is in the DOM but not necessarily interactable. Use `EC.element_to_be_clickable()` if you are going to click something and `EC.visibility_of_element_located()` if you are going to interact with an element like `.send_keys()` or get `.text`.

The code below is working.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.racingandsports.com.au/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btn_login"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "lb-username"))).send_keys("your_username")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "lb-password"))).send_keys("your_password")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnLogin"))).click()    
# continue script, make sure for the first element (at least) you add another wait

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

[SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) can handle that site:

`pip install seleniumbase`, then run the following with `python` or `pytest`:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)

class ExampleTest(BaseCase):
    def test_example(self):
        self.open("https://www.racingandsports.com.au/")
        self.click("a#btn_login")
        self.type('input[placeholder*="Username"]', "your_username")
        self.type('input[placeholder*="Password"]', "your_password")
        self.sleep(10)
```

Comment: thank you very much, I haven't used selenium base before but it seem a good thing to learn